# SOA XSLT Increment a counter variable in outer for loop and inner loop

Tags: xslt, soa

I need to map an incremental variable in XSLT to a target column. 
Below is the pseudo code am expecting to be done in XSLT.

varcounter = 0

for each outer loop

print varcounter

```
 varcounter = varcounter +1
```

for each inner loop

```
print varcounter
```

varcounter = varcounter +1

end for each inner loop

end for each outer loop.

Incrementing is not supported in SOA XSLT.
I cant use position() as well as the variable needs to be persisted between outer and inner for loops.

Please suggest how can implement using a template or any other ways.

Comment: Your pseudo code is pretty much useless in a functional language such as XSLT. Why don't you post a small example of XML input and explain what do you want to get as the output?

Comment: Ok. let me explain my requirement. I have list of employees in xml with data elements as 1. Emp_ID 2. Department_Id, 3. Sub_dep_id

Comment: Now i Need to map to the target document by grouping first with department and then sub_department along with its employess. Along with each entity a unique sequence needs to be generated just beside to it.
Department_Id1, 1

    Sub_Dept1,2

          Emp_Id1, 3

          Emp_Id2, 4

    Sub_Dept2,5

          Emp_Id3,6

          Emp_Id4,7

Department_Id2,8

    Sub Dept3, 9
          Emp_Id5,10

Comment: This is difficult to follow. Please edit your question and post your XML input (as code) and the expected output (also as code).